# JavaDoc: If the @param comment does not fit in one line

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

If the @param comment does not fit in one line, will JavaDoc recognize words written in a newline as information regarding the method's parameters?

Comment: Have you tried? Would have been quicker than composing the _question_. That little research effort would have answered your _question_...

Comment: I am having issues with my IDE that I am trying to resolve that impair me from generating a JavaDoc.

Comment: You should solve those issues first, than, or use the `javadoc` command line tool.

Comment: Interestingly, this is the first hit on google for "javadoc line continuation" now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can continue the description on new lines. For instance:

```
/*
 * . . .
 * @param p
 *            text describing the parameter can overflow the
 *            line. It doesn't even have to start on the line.
 *            Indenting is not necessary, but it's nice for
 *            readability. The asterisk at the start of each
 *            line does not appear in the docs. The description
 *            ends at the start of the next "@..." tag or the
 *            end of the comment block.
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do more then one line's worth of info for a `@param`, examples taken and modified from Oracle's ["how to write javadoc"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html):

```
/**
 * Registers the text to display in a tool tip.   The text 
 * displays when the cursor lingers over the component.
 *
 * @param text  the string to display.  If the text is null, 
 *              the tool tip is turned off for this component.
```

You can also do more then one `@param` entery:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
```